# Why does dbscan perform poorly on this dataset

Tags: data-science, cluster-analysis

I have the following dataset and I am using the dbscan algorithm to try and perform clustering.
[image]

However no matter what values for min points and eps I choose I get very few and very bad clusters. Isn't dbscan supposed to perform well on clusters of similar density that are separated by some outliers?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out dbscan works just fine I just had to not only use the eps indicated by the elbow plot but try different value of eps for a specific amount of min points on intuition.